# ARM + FPGA board for industrial Product development

Tags: fpga, embedded, arm

I am using mini2440 board with external FPGA board, I am looking for one ARM+FPGA board with GPIO support.

As of now I am using mini2440 board with GPIO to control the hardware and sometimes using USB FPGA board to control the hardware. I am looking for the board with has ARM+FPGA support so that I can connect my hardware to the board to reduce the hardware.

Please let me know If you know any ARM+FPGA board in whcih i can port Linux and use it for industrial application.

Comment: Perhaps http://www.xilinx.com/products/silicon-devices/soc/zynq-7000/index.htm

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the Xilinx Zynq family (there is also a board available, the [Zedboard](http://www.zedboard.org/)), this is a FPGA with a hard Cortex-A9 core.

Since this is fairly new, please check if the software support is what you need.

Comment: @Tom, Thanks for the reference. I will definitely look into the board and let you know. Thank you for your time.